# Broken Taxonomy Links WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

If I'm in the wp-admin panel, and click "view" on a custom post, I get an url like this:

```
http://demosite.v2.test/property/%city2%/some-place/
```

Which doesn't work and leads to a 400 (Bad Request) page.

However, the following link does work:

```
http://demosite.v2.test/property/city2/some-place/
```

How would you fix this?

Comment: can you show how the custom post type and taxonomies are being set in the code?

Comment: Also, please provide your permalink rules

Comment: Answer was in the Permalinks options. Removed % from the city2 taxonomy. Thanks :)